# animation on link click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, cordova

Alright I have no idea how to phrase, and I'm new to StackExchange so I hope this is in the right place.

Anyway, I'm working on a mobile HTML5 app right now, one that uses Phonegap/Cordova (and Bootstrap), and I wanted to have an animation whenever a user clicks on a link.

So when a user clicks the link, there will be a page transition to the left, and the linked page pops up.

How could I do this in CSS/JS?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to try something before you ask for [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "How could I do this in CSS/JS"? ... You can use Angular, here is an example: http://angular-transitions.mgechev.com/#/view/page1

Comment: For a start you can try using JqueryMobile that provides a lot of features and themes specially for mobile apps.
For example you have mobile.changePage(#PageName) that allows you to change page and also choose animations for it.

If you are really interested in doing it by yourself, you can download the css of JQM and look what they are doing there when animating after using changePage function.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

To design an HTML5 mobile app, i will strongly recommand using a front framework, like jquery mobile, ionic or onsenui.

Here is how you can simply do the swipe transition with jquery mobile : http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_trans_slide

Hope this help